# Как записать данные в ячейку excel с помощью Aspose.Cells C#?

Tags: c#

при работе программы вылезает ошибка:
System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

Aspose.Cells.Cells.GetCell(...) вернул null.

Код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Aspose.Cells;

namespace App
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //StreamReader inputFile = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\pavle\\Documents\\repos\\tableexcel4bigramm\\App\\input.txt");
            Workbook output = new Workbook("C:\\Users\\pavle\\Documents\\repos\\tableexcel4bigramm\\App\\output3.xlsx");
            Dictionary<char, int> letterCountDict = new Dictionary<char, int>();
            Dictionary<string, int> bigrammDict = new Dictionary<string, int>(); 
            Worksheet worksheet = output.Worksheets[0];

            string text = "";
            using (StreamReader inputFile = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\pavle\\Documents\\repos\\tableexcel4bigramm\\App\\input.txt"))
            {
                text = inputFile.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(text);
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
            {
                //Добавление (обновление) в словарь Буква-Кол-во_повторений
                    if (letterCountDict.ContainsKey(text[i]))
                    {
                        letterCountDict[text[i]]++;
                    } else
                    {
                        letterCountDict.Add(text[i], 1);
                    }

                    if (i != text.Length - 1)
                    {
                        string bigramm = "";
                        bigramm.Append(text[i]);
                        bigramm.Append(text[i + 1]);

                        //Добавление (обновление) в словарь биграмма-Кол-во_повторений
                        if (bigrammDict.ContainsKey(bigramm))
                        {
                            bigrammDict[bigramm]++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            bigrammDict.Add(bigramm, 1);
                        }
                    }
                }

            foreach (var letter in letterCountDict)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(letter);
            }

            //создание таблицы для bigramm
            int n = 1;
            foreach (char letter in letterCountDict.Keys)
            {
                worksheet.Cells.GetCell(n, 1).PutValue(letter);
                worksheet.Cells.GetCell(1, n).PutValue(letter);
                n++;
            }

            //заполнение таблицы
            for (int i = 2; i < letterCountDict.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 2; j < letterCountDict.Count; j++)
                {
                    string bigrammRow = worksheet.Cells.GetCell(i, 1).Value.ToString();
                    string bigrammCol = worksheet.Cells.GetCell(1, j).Value.ToString();
                    string bigramm = bigrammRow + bigrammCol;
                    if (bigrammDict.ContainsKey(bigramm))
                    {
                        worksheet.Cells.GetCell(i, j).Value = bigrammDict[bigramm]; 
                    } else
                    {
                        worksheet.Cells.GetCell(i, j).Value = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            //inputFile.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В отличие от Excel, [библиотека от Apose работает только с тем, что есть в файле. Если ячейки в файле нет, то возвращается null](https://reference.aspose.com/cells/net/aspose.cells/cells/getcell/).

Поэтому, если GetCell возвращает null, нужно [создать отсутствующую ячейку](https://reference.aspose.com/cells/net/aspose.cells/cells/createrange/).

Comment: Как продвигается решение?